# Vue Component not showing store data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I am building a trivia maker. I am currently working on the edit page for a question. The edit component, named EditQAForm, grabs the question and answers for that particular question and populates each of it's respective VueX store's form.

I am currently having trouble with the answers portion of this page. When the EditQAForm is mounted it calls the fetchQuestionAnswers, which retrieves all the answers for that particular question. It does this correctly, but then when I try to display any of the answers onto the page, it says that the form is empty despite me seeing in the Vue DevTools that it is not empty.

(Please note I deleted stuff that wasnt relevant to this. So assume all methods you see called do exist)

Here is the mounted for the EditQAForm:

```
mounted() {

            //gets the params from the url
            this.routeParams = this.$route.params;

            //gets the answers that belong to this question
            this.fetchQuestionAnswers(this.routeParams.question_id);

            //not important for this problem
            //get the question that needs to be edited
            this.fetchQuestion(this.routeParams.question_id);

        },
```

How I call it in the computed properties of the EditQAForm:

```
computed: {
            ...mapGetters('question', ['formQuestionRoundID', 'questions', 'questionFields']),
            ...mapGetters('answer', ['answerFields', 'answers']),

            //Questions
            questionForm: {
                get() {
                    return this.questionFields;
                },
            },

            //Answers
            answerForm: {
                get() {
                    return this.answerFields;
                },
            },
        }
```

Here is the store for the answers

```
function initialState() {
    return {
        answers: [],
        answer: null,
        form: [
            {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                question_id: '',
                round_id: '',
                correct: false,
            },
            {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                question_id: '',
                round_id: '',
                correct: false,
            },
            {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                question_id: '',
                round_id: '',
                correct: false,
            },
        ]
    }
}

const getters = {
    answers(state){
        return state.answers;
    },
    answerFields(state){
        return state.form;
    },
    loading(state){
        return state.loading;
    },
};

const actions = {

    fetchQuestionAnswers({ commit, state }, question_id) {
        console.log("Form outside axios:");
        console.log(state.form);
        commit('setLoading', true);
        axios.get('/api/question/' + question_id + '/answers')
            .then(response => {
                commit('SET_ANSWERS_FORM', response.data);
                commit('setLoading', false);
            }).catch( error => {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    },

const mutations = {

    SET_ANSWERS_FORM(state, answers){

        for(let $i = 0; $i < answers.length; $i++)
        {
            state.form[$i] = {
                id: answers[$i].id,
                title: answers[$i].title,
                question_id: answers[$i].question_id,
                round_id: answers[$i].round_id,
                correct: answers[$i].correct,
            }
        }
        // state.answers = answers;
    },
    UPDATE_TITLE(state, payload){
        state.form[payload.order].title = payload.title;
    },
    UPDATE_QUESTION_ID(state,payload){
        state.form[payload.order].question_id = payload.questionID;
    },
};
```

What I try outputting:

```
    <div>

        <h3 class="pb-3">Is first answer's title not empty?: {{!(answerForm[1].title === '')}}</h3>
        <h3 class="pb-3">{{answerForm[0].title }}</h3>

        <h3>{{answerForm}}</h3>

    </div>
```

What shows on my screen, alongside what devtools tells me is inside the answerForm array:

[image]

I implemented the question portion in a very similar way. The only difference is that the form is not an array in the question store, but besides that it works fine. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```js
state.form[$i] = {
```

If you use an index to update an array it won't trigger the reactivity system and you'll get a stale version of the rendered components. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

There are various ways to fix this. You could use `Vue.set` or alternatively just create am entirely new array.

Not entirely clear to me why you're doing all that copying in the first place rather than just using `state.form = answers`, which would also solve the problem.